# If $a+b+c=abc$ then $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{7a+b}\leq\frac{\sqrt3}{8}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers such that $a+b+c=abc$. Prove that:
$$\frac{1}{7a+b}+\frac{1}{7b+c}+\frac{1}{7c+a}\leq\frac{\sqrt3}{8}$$

I tried C-S:
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{7a+b}\right)^2\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(ka+mb+c)(7a+b)^2}\sum_{cyc}(ka+mb+c)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(k+m+1)(a+b+c)}{(ka+mb+c)(7a+b)^2}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{k+m+1}{(ka+mb+c)(7a+b)^2}\leq\frac{3}{64abc},$$
but I did not find non-negative values of $k$ and $m$, for which the last inequality is true.

If we replace $7$ with $8$ so for $(a,b,c)||(28,1,5)$ this inequality would be wrong. Around this point the starting inequality is true, but we see that we can'not free use AM-GM because in AM-GM the equality occurs, when all variables are equal.

Thank you!

Comment: FOr those fans who hate abbreviations, C-S is Cauchy-Schwartz

Comment: As a good start, take $a=\sqrt{3}x, b = \sqrt{3}y, c = \sqrt{3}z$ so that you are working with $x+y+z = 3xyz$ and the extremum will occur at $(1,1,1)$. Makes the horrendous algebra a little cleaner.

Comment: @W-t-P It's cyclic and not symmetric.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Maybe BW helps? Though it doesn't seem to be particularly elegant...

Comment: @user574848 I tried. I think BW does not help here.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Ah ok. Is this your inequality?

Comment: @user574848 Yes, it's my inequality.

Comment: The two variable case is even complicated for me. i.e. $ab=a+b$ then $\frac{1}{7a+b}+\frac{1}{7b+a}\leq\frac{\sqrt 2}{8}$. By my calculations, it is equivalent to finding maximum of $\frac{8(b-1)}{(6+b)(7b-6)}$ for $b>0$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  Actually BW works. See my solution.

Answer (score 4):

let $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{a},y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{b},z=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{c} \implies xy+yz+zx=3 $

with uvw method:

$3u=x+y+z,3v^2=xy+yz+zx,w^3=xyz\\ u\geqslant v \geqslant w \geqslant 0 , w^3 \leq 3uv^2 -2u^3+2\sqrt{(u^2-v^2)^3}, v=1 $

then inequality becomes:

$\frac{xy}{7y+x}+\frac{yz}{7z+y}+\frac{xz}{7x+z}\leq\frac{3}{8}  \iff \\3(7y+x)(7z+y)(7x+z) \geqslant 8[xy(7z+y)(7x+z)+yz(7y+x)(7x+z)+xz(7y+x)(7z+y)]$ \

$LHS=3[7(7yz^2+xz^2+y^2z+7x^2z+7xy^2+x^2y)+344xyz]\\7yz^2+xz^2+y^2z+7x^2z+7xy^2+x^2y=4\sum(x^2y+y^2x)+3(yz^2+x^2z+xy^2-xz^2-y^2z-x^2y)=4\sum xy(x+y+z-z)+3(y-x)(z-x)(z-y)=4(x+y+z)\sum xy -4*3xyz+3(y-x)(z-x)(z-y) \\ LHS=3[7*4*3^2u+260w^3+3*7(y-x)(z-x)(z-y)]\\ RHS=8[\sum_{cyc}xy(7z+y)(7x+z)]=8[7\sum x^2y^2+57xyz(x+y+z)]\\= 8[ 7((xy+yz+xz)^2-2xyz(x+y+z))+57xyz(x+y+z)] \\=8(63+43*3u*w^3)$

then the inequality becomes:

$4(63u+65w^3-42-86uw^3) \geq 21(x-y)(z-x)(z-y) ....(3)$

now to prove

$63u+65w^3-42-86uw^3 \geq 0 \iff w^3 \leq \dfrac{63u-42}{86u-65}$

first to prove :

$\dfrac{63u-42}{86u-65} \geq \dfrac{2u-1}{4u-3} \iff (u-1)(80u-61)   $it is true as $u\geq 1$

second to prove

$\dfrac{2u-1}{4u-3} \geq 3u-2u^3+2\sqrt{(u^2-1)^3} \iff \\ (2u^3-3u)(4u-3)+2u-1 \geq 2(4u-3)\sqrt{(u^2-1)^3} \iff (u-1)(8u^3+2u^2-10u+1) \geq 2(4u-3)(u^2-1)\sqrt{(u^2-1)} \iff (u-1)^2[(8u^3+2u^2-10u+1)^2-4(4u-3)^2(u+1)^2(u^2-1)] \geq 0 \iff (u-1)^2(32u^3-24u^2-44u+37) \geq 0 $

$(u-1)^2 \geq 0$ ,it remains $h(u)=32u^3-24u^2-44u+37>0 $
$h'(u)=96*u^2-48*u-44 ,$  let $h'(u)=0 $ we have 
$u_1=\dfrac{5\sqrt3+3}{12},u_2=-\dfrac{5\sqrt3-3}{12}<0$

it is easy to verify that $h_{min}=h(u_1)=\dfrac{25(9-5\sqrt3)}{9}>0$

so $63u+65w^3-42-86uw^3 \geq 0$ is true and when and only when $u=1$ it takes $0$. when $u=v \implies x=y=z$

check RHS of (3) , if $(x-y)(z-x)(z-y) \leq 0$ , then (3) is true. when $(x-y)(z-x)(z-y) \geq 0$ , square both sides, we need to porve :

$4^2(63u+65w^3-42-86uw^3)^2 \geq 21^2 [(x-y)(z-x)(z-y)]^2$...(4)

$[(x-y)(z-x)(z-y)]^2=27[4(u^2-v^2)^3-(w^3-3uv^2+2u^2)^2]=27[4(u^2-1)^3-(w^3-3u+2u^3)^2]$

then the (4) becomes:
$A(u)w^6+B(u)w^3+C(u) \geq 0 \\ A(u)=43(2752u^2-4160u+1849) >0 as 4160^2-4*2752*1849=-3048192 <0 \\ B(u)=42(1134u^3-4128u^2+4171u-2080) \\ C(u)=441(63u^2-192u+172)>0 as 192^2-4*63*172=-6480  <0$

let $t=w^3\implies 0\leq t\leq 1, A(u)w^6+B(u)w^3+C(u)=At^2+Bt+C=f(t)$

when $-\dfrac{B}{2A} \leq 0 , f_{min}=f(0)=C(u)>0$
when $-\dfrac{B}{2A} \geq 1 ,f_{min}=f(1)=A(u)+B(u)+C(u)=(u-1)^2(47628u+67999) \geq 0 $

when $0 \leq -\dfrac{B}{2A} \leq 1 \iff 42(1134u^3-4128u^2+4171u-2080)<0 $ and  $-42(1134u^3-4128u^2+4171u-2080) \leq 2*43*(2752*u^2-4160*u+1849) $

we will prove $B^2-4AC<0$

$-42(1134u^3-4128u^2+4171u-2080) \leq 2*43*(2752u^2-4160u+1849) \iff \\ 2(u-1)(23814u^2+55462u-35827) \geq 0$ it is always true

let $g(u)=1134u^3-4128u^2+4171u-2080$, it is trivial that

$1134u^3-4128u^2+4171u-1909.536 \geq g(u) \geq 1134u^3-4128u^2+4171*u-5979$

$1134*u^3-4128*u^2+4171*u-1909.536=((u-2.4)*(28350*u^2-35160*u+19891))/25$

$(28350*u^2-35160*u+19891)=0 $ no real root as $35160^2-4*28350*19891=-1019413800 <0$

$1134*u^3-4128*u^2+4171*u-5979=(u-3)*(1134*u^2-726*u+1993)$

it is trivial that $1134*u^2-726*u+1993$ no real root.

which  means $g(u)$ only have one real root $u_3$ and $2.4 <u_3 <3$

$g'(u)=3402*u^2-8256*u+4171,8256/(2*3402)=1.213<1.3,g'(2)=1267>0 \implies g(u) $
is mono increase function when $u>2 \implies \\$

$B(u)<0 $ when $u<u_3 $

now we prove when $u<3, B^2-4AC \leq 0$

$B^2-4AC=190512(u-1)^2*(11907u^4-62874u^3+38688u^2+92442*u-86563)$

$11907u^4-62874u^3+38688u^2+92442u-86563=11907(u-3)(u^2-1)(u-1)-2(7623u^3-7437u^2-22407u+25421)\\7623*u^3-7437*u^2-22407*u+25421=(7623*u^3-7443*u^2-22410*u+25416)+(6u^2+3u+5) \\7623u^3-7443u^2-22410u+25416=9(847u^3-827u^2-2490u+2824)$

$(847u^3-827u^2-2490u+2824)'_u=2541u^2-1654u-2490=0 , $

we have two roots

$u_4=\dfrac{\sqrt{7011019}+827}{2541},\\u_5=\dfrac{-\sqrt{7011019}+827}{2541} <0 $

it is easy to verify  that $(847u^3-827u^2-2490u+2824)_{min}=847u_4^3-827u_4^2-2490u_4+2824>38>0$

so $B^2-4AC \leq 0$ is true .

QED

Comment: That's brute. Though it is legitimate as a proof, I think the OP needs a more elegant method.

Comment: How long did this take you? :D

Comment: @chenbai Thank you for your trying. I also have a proof because this inequality it' just a cubic inequality of $v^2$, which gives a very ugly solution. I looked for a proof, which we can write during a competition.

Comment: yes, it is a ugly proof. I knew it is impossible to finish in the competition. and I do have same hope to see some elegant  method. Hope this ugly proof may take some better ones come. it takes me a longtime indeed.:)

Answer (score 4):

The Buffalo Way works.

After homogenization, it suffices to prove that $f(a,b,c)\ge 0$ where $f(a,b,c)$ is a polynomial given by
\begin{align}
f(a,b,c) &= 64abc(7a+b)^2(7b+c)^2(7c+a)^2\\
&\quad \times\left(\frac{3}{64}\frac{a+b+c}{abc} - \left(\frac{1}{7a+b} + \frac{1}{7b+c} + \frac{1}{7c+a}\right)^2\right).
\end{align}

WLOG, assume that $c = \min(a, b, c).$ There are two possible cases:

1) $c \le b\le a$: Let $c = 1, \ b = 1+s, \ a = 1+s+t; \ s,t\ge 0$.
$f(1+s+t, 1+s, 1)$ is a polynomial in $s, t$ with non-negative coefficients. So $f(1+s+t, 1+s, 1)\ge 0.$

2) $c \le a\le b$: Let $c =1, \ a=1+s, \ b=1+s+t; \ s,t\ge 0$. We have
\begin{align}
f(1+s, 1+s+t, 1) = a_5t^5 + a_4t^4 + a_3t^3 + a_2t^2 + a_1t + a_0
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
a_5 &= 147\, s^2 - 784\, s + 6272,\\
a_4 &= 2940\, s^3 - 16583\, s^2 + 53648\, s + 82432 ,\\
a_3 &= 19551\, s^4 - 94494\, s^3 - 65760\, s^2 + 185344\, s + 139264,\\
a_2 &= 49686\, s^5 - 68407\, s^4 - 242656\, s^3 + 13824\, s^2 + 220160\, s + 81920,\\
a_1 &= 51744\, s^6 + 97584\, s^5 + 88848\, s^4 + 173056\, s^3 + 211968\, s^2 + 81920\, s ,\\
a_0 &= 81920\, s^2 + 270336\, s^3 + 344576\, s^4 + 224640\, s^5 + 87296\, s^6 + 18816\, s^7.
\end{align}
It is easy to obtain that $a_5, a_4, a_1, a_0 \ge 0$. Thus, we have
$$f(1+s, 1+s+t, 1)\ge (2\sqrt{a_5a_1} + a_3)t^3 + (2\sqrt{a_4a_0} + a_2)t^2.$$

It suffices to prove that $2\sqrt{a_5a_1} + a_3 \ge 0$ and $2\sqrt{a_4a_0} + a_2 \ge 0$.

Note that 
\begin{align}
2\sqrt{a_5a_1} + a_3 &= \Big(2\sqrt{a_5a_1} - \frac{1}{3}\cdot 94494\, s^3 - \frac{1}{3} \cdot 65760\, s^2\Big)\\
&\quad + \Big(a_3 + \frac{1}{3}\cdot 94494\, s^3 + \frac{1}{3} \cdot 65760\, s^2\Big)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
2\sqrt{a_4a_0} + a_2 &= \Big(2\sqrt{a_4a_0} - \frac{1}{2}\cdot 68407\, s^4 - \frac{1}{2}242656\, s^3\Big)\\
&\quad + \Big(a_2 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot 68407\, s^4 + \frac{1}{2}242656\, s^3\Big).
\end{align}
It suffices to prove that
\begin{align}
2\sqrt{a_5a_1} - \frac{1}{3}\cdot 94494\, s^3 - \frac{1}{3} \cdot 65760\, s^2 &\ge 0,\\
a_3 + \frac{1}{3}\cdot 94494\, s^3 + \frac{1}{3} \cdot 65760\, s^2&\ge 0,\\
2\sqrt{a_4a_0} - \frac{1}{2}\cdot 68407\, s^4 - \frac{1}{2}242656\, s^3 &\ge 0,\\
a_2 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot 68407\, s^4 + \frac{1}{2}242656\, s^3 &\ge 0.
\end{align}
All of them can be reduced to polynomial inequalities in $s$ and not hard to prove. This completes the proof.

Comment: You kill it ! I cannot find better than this ! thanks !

Comment: @ErikSatie Thanks!

Comment: For the unenlightened among us: What is "the Buffalo way"?

Comment: @IgorRivin Thanks for comment. One can see: https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/the-buffalo-way/

Comment: Ah! Truly you are wise in the ways of science.

Comment: I personally hate these inequality problems with a passion, so this satisfies my baser instincts.

Comment: Also, this explains how these problems are generated....

Comment: @IgorRivin Yes, you may see nice inequality problems in contests such as IMO etc. However, the problems that one typically faces at research level are not problems carefully crafted. One example is the inequality problem (related to quantum phase transition) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427324/prove-sum-k-1n-sqrtx22x-cos-frac2k-1-pi2n-1-ge-1-sum-k-1

Comment: That looks like a nice question, but for those there is usually a conceptual argument, not some magic sequence of tricks. By the way, I notice that still has no accepted answer...

Comment: @IgorRivin Yes, no rigorous/step-by-step answer has been posted yet.

Answer (score 1):

Not a proof just a simplification for the proof wich already exists :

We prove the following inequality :

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $abc=a+b+c$ and $a\geq b \geq c$ then we have :
>   $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{7a+b}\leq \sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{7b+a}$$

Proof :

We work with the following equivalent :

> Let $a,b,c>0$  and $a\geq b \geq c$ then we have :
>   $$\sqrt{\frac{abc}{a+b+c}}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{7a+b}\leq \sqrt{\frac{abc}{a+b+c}}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{7b+a}$$

Remains to show :

> Let $a,b,c>0$  and $a\geq b \geq c$ then we have :
>   $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{7a+b}\leq \sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{7b+a}$$

We make the difference we get :

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{7a+b}-\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{7b+a}=-\frac{(42 (a - b) (a - c) (b - c) (7 a^2 + 57 a b + 57 a c + 7 b^2 + 57 b c + 7 c^2))}{((7 a + b) (a + 7 b) (7 a + c) (a + 7 c) (7 b + c) (b + 7 c))}\leq 0$$

I think it simplify a part of the proof of River Li and maybe create a new approach to solve the initial inequality.

Answer (score 1):

My second solution:

Remark: Using the Buffalo Way as well, but it is simpler.

Use @**chenbai**'s substitutions $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{a}, y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{b}, z=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{c}$.
We have $xy+yz+zx=3$. We need to prove that
$$\frac{xy}{x + 7y}+\frac{yz}{y + 7z}+\frac{zx}{z+7x}\leq\frac{3}{8}.$$

After homogenization, it suffices to prove that
$$\Big(\frac{xy}{x + 7y}+\frac{yz}{y + 7z}+\frac{zx}{z+7x}\Big)^2 \leq \frac{9}{64}\frac{xy+yz+zx}{3}$$
or (clearing the denominators)
$$f(x, y, z) \ge 0$$
where $f(x, y, z)$ is a homogeneous polynomial.

WLOG, assume $z = \min(x, y, z)$. Let $x = z + s, y = z + t$ for $s, t\ge 0$. We have
$$f(z + s, z + t, z) = q_6z^6 + q_5 z^5 + q_4 z^4 + q_3 z^3 + q_2 z^2 + q_1 z + q_0$$
where
\begin{align*}
q_6 &= 81920 s^2-81920 s t+81920 t^2, \\
q_5 &= 106496 s^3-107520 s^2 t+279552 s t^2+106496 t^3, \\
q_4 &= 49664 s^4-155648 s^3 t+312832 s^2 t^2+489472 s t^3+49664 t^4, \\
q_3 &= 18816 s^5-97904 s^4 t-39200 s^3 t^2+650272 s^2 t^3+202480 s t^4+18816 t^5,\\
q_2 &= 14112 s^5 t-135143 s^4 t^2+239198 s^3 t^3+244873 s^2 t^4+42336 s t^5, \\
q_1 &= 2646 s^5 t^2-23590 s^4 t^3+91322 s^3 t^4+30870 s^2 t^5, \\
q_0 &= 147 s^5 t^3-1078 s^4 t^4+7203 s^3 t^5.
\end{align*}
It is easy to prove that $q_5, q_4, q_3, q_1, q_0 \ge 0$. It suffices to prove that $4q_3 q_1 \ge q_2^2$ or
\begin{align}
&s^2 t^3\Big(1002582336 s^7-9318167153 s^6 t+34882209252 s^5 t^2-77849923910 s^4 t^3\\
&\quad +108085842468 s^3 t^4+72267463855 s^2 t^5+11141602752 s t^6+531062784 t^7\Big) \ge 0
\end{align}
which is true.

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

This inequality is something hard

$  a\geq b\geq\sqrt{3}\geq c>0$  such that $abc=a+b+c$ and constraints $(C)$ and $(2)$ and $(3)$  then we have :

$$\frac{1}{7b+a}+\frac{1}{7a+c}+\frac{1}{7c+b}\leq \left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)\frac{1}{1+7\left(\frac{\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+3}{9}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$

And :

$$\frac{1}{7b+a}\leq \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)\frac{1}{1+7\left(\frac{\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+3}{9}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\quad (C)$$

$$\frac{1}{7c+b}+\frac{1}{7a+c}\leq \left(\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{a}\right)\frac{1}{1+7\left(\frac{\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+3}{9}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\quad (2)$$

Simplify the condition $(C)$ is easy comparing the function :

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{7x+1}$$

Or:

$$f\Big(\frac{6+\frac{a}{b}}{7}\Big)\leq f\left(\left(\frac{\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+3}{9}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)$$

For the constraint $(2)$ we know that :

$$f(a)=\frac{1}{7c+b}+\frac{1}{7a+c}-\left(\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{a}\right)\frac{1}{1+7\left(\frac{\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+3}{9}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$

is an increasing function (as the difference of a positive decreasing function and a negative increasing function)  on $(\sqrt{3},\frac{\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{3}-\frac{1}{2}c+c}{c(\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{3}-\frac{1}{2}c)-1})$ with :
$$b=\frac{a+c}{ac-1}$$

So we have to find an approximation of the roots !

We can choose $b\geq\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{3}-\frac{1}{2}c\quad (3)$

A bit of algebra and we get a polynomial with a root equal to $\sqrt{3}$ and one other root .Now the magic key is,the inequality and the constraints $(C),(2)$ are homogenous so we can introduce a coefficient and play with it keeping in mind the others constraints.

I continue later...Thanks!

Comment: Please check $\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{7a+b}\leq \sum_{cyc}\frac{2}{14a+b+c}$
for $a = 2$, $b = 2, c = 4/3$.

Comment: @RiverLi Do you see a counter-example ? Thanks and good day !

Comment: Numerically, it appears all of three are not true.

Comment: @RiverLi have you an explicit counter-example because I think the first is true .

Comment: The 3rd one: Check $a = 70/9, b = 26/5, c = (a+b)/(ab - 1)$.

Comment: The 1st and 2nd: Check $a = 25/4, b = 19/10, c = (a+b)/(ab - 1)$.

Comment: @RiverLi Well I think it works for the values which are close to $\sqrt{3}$ now . Sorry if it's a little bit boring .If you have an counter-example now I shall delete this attemp (and give you a point for your effort because your proof is nice !)

Comment: I think it is true when $a,b, c$ are sufficiently close to $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @RiverLi I solve the third inequality but a last question : Can we use Buffalo's way for the second inequality or something easier ?If you have a proof I shall open a question for you ! Thanks !

Comment: Your constraint is complicated. Too hard.

Comment: @RiverLi I know that it's not a perfect sketch of proof but what do you think ?Thanks !

Comment: Actually it is quite difficult, I think.

Comment: @RiverLi well it works but it's unprovable so...I let it if someone have an idea .

Comment: If you can easily eliminate the constraints to get a polynomial inequality $f(x, y, z)\ge 0$ where $x, y, z \ge 0$, there is a hope to use BW.

Comment: @RiverLi thanks I shall try it !

Comment: @RiverLi I go further can you tell me if there is no wrong notes !

Comment: Your constraint (2) includes two inequalities?

Comment: @RiverLi just one solved it is clearer ?Nota bene : it seems to ambiguous to use the homegeneity at the end .Thanks.

Comment: Now there are two (1).

Comment: @RiverLi minor problem corrected ! Thanks for the help !

Comment: It seems not true under constraints (1)(2). Check $a = {\frac {29991}{5000}}$, $b = {\frac {22667}{10000}}$ and $c = (a + b)/(ab - 1)$.

Comment: @RiverLi You forgot the constraint $b\geq\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{3}-\frac{1}{2}c$

Comment: Please add it in the 2nd line.

Comment: It seems not yet true. Check $a = {\frac {29997}{5000}}, b = {\frac {11387}{5000}}$ and $c = (a+b)/(ab - 1)$.

Comment: @RiverLi I'm so thanksfull ^^! I come back to the first version and add what you want !Now I'm very tired because I work in a school so again thanks !