# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{x^2+2x\cos\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n} + 1}\ge 1+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{x^2+2x\cos\frac{2k\pi}{2n} + 1}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, complex-numbers, products, roots-of-unity

For nonnegative real number $x \ge 0$, and positive integer $n>0$,prove that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{x^2+2x\cos\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n} + 1} \ge 1+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{x^2+2x\cos\frac{2k\pi}{2n} + 1}$$
where equality holds when $x=0$.

(PS: I am not sure whether the inequality holds for $0\le x \le cos\frac{\pi}{2n}$)

(The idea is from here: https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0509490, left down corner of page 2, "The parity of the number of c-quasiparticles is a good quantum number and the ground state has even parity for any value of g.")

【newly updated:】
Let $y = f(x)= \sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{x^2+2x\cos\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n} + 1} -( 1+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{x^2+2x\cos\frac{2k\pi}{2n} + 1})$,

for 2n=100 and 2n=200, draw f(x)'s graphics with mathematica, as follows:
the inequality holds for $ x \ge cos\frac{\pi}{2n}$,

So, the question is: in interval[0,$cos\frac{\pi}{2n}$), inequality holds with computer's numerical error or not holds?
[image: 2n=100]

[image: 2n=200]

Comment: Posts that only state a problem are discouraged on this site. Please improve the post by adding additional context: where did you encounter the problem? Why is it of interest? What relationships with other problems, or applications, might it have? These things add value to the post and help readers appreciate the problem.

Comment: Wangwang. Term-by-term?

Comment: I was intrigued by this because of another inequality somewhat similar to this, $$\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sqrt{x^2+1+2x\cos\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n}} }{n} \leq \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{x^2+1+2x\cos\frac{(2k)\pi}{2n}} }{n-1} $$.  That can be proved using Jensen's inequality.   But in the OP's question, with sums, rather than averages, and the extra 1 on the RHS, the inequality is reversed.  No luck proving or disproving it yet.

Comment: $RHS=1+ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{x^2+2xcos\frac{2k\pi}{2n} + 1} - \sqrt{x^2-2x+1} = x+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{x^2+2xcos\frac{2k\pi}{2n} + 1}$, for $ 0\le x \le 1$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. When $z=e^{i\phi}$ we have $|x+z|=\sqrt{x^2+2x\cos\phi+1}$.
2. When $x=0$ the claimed inequality holds with equality.
3. If $0<\alpha<\beta<\pi/2$ then $|x+e^{i\alpha}|\ge |x+e^{i\beta}|$ for all $x\ge0$. Draw a picture if you don't see why this is true!