# Hard inequality with condition ($xyz=1$)

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

It's a new inequality that I have created this is the following :

> Let $x,y,z$ be real positive numbers such that $xyz=1$ then we have :
>   $$\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{(\frac{z}{x})^{\frac{1}{2}}}{(z+1+\frac{1}{x})^{\frac{1}{2}}(7+\frac{1}{x})}\leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}$$

I have tried to apply Jensen's inequality to the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{7+\frac{1}{x}}$ wich is concave but we don't get a good expression .
I also tried to expand the expression but it fails .
After this I have no idea to prove this...

Any hints would be appreciable.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean that "you have created "?

Comment: Is this related to an actual mathematical contest, as described in the [contest-math tag wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/contest-math/info)? In that case it would be appropriate to add a source to the contest (compare https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28999/42969). Otherwise you can remove the tag.

Comment: The variable $y$ does not explicitly appear in your left-hand side.  Perhaps you intend for the "cyclic" summation to be taken in a particular order, but with only $x,z$ shown, it may be slightly ambiguous which three(?) terms are meant to be added.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\frac{a}{b}$ and $y=\frac{b}{c},$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positives.

Thus, $z=\frac{c}{a}$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{7a+b}\leq\frac{1}{8}\sqrt{\frac{3(a+b+c)}{abc}},$$
which was here:

[If $a+b+c=abc$ then $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{7a+b}\leq\frac{\sqrt3}{8}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197138)

Comment: But that other inequality has no proof either. – My *guess* would be that this question was posted as an attempt to solve your older problem.