# Trigonometric inequality : $\sum_{cyc}\tan\Big(\frac{1}{7a+b}\Big)\leq 3\tan\Big(\frac{1}{8\sqrt{3}}\Big)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I have finally found the right function such that we have :

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $abc=a+b+c$ then we have :
>   $$\sum_{cyc}\tan\Big(\frac{1}{7a+b}\Big)\leq 3\tan\Big(\frac{1}{8\sqrt{3}}\Big)$$

To underline the difficulty we have also :

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $\pi=a+b+c$ and $a,b,c<\frac{\pi}{2}$then we have :
>   $$\sum_{cyc}\tan\Big(\frac{1}{7\tan(a)+\tan(b)}\Big)\leq 3\tan\Big(\frac{1}{8\sqrt{3}}\Big)$$

It's more impressive like this and I don't know what to do with this in fact it's more a present for Michael Rozenberg .

I accept ugly proof but I think it's too hard to find .

Any hint would be appreciable .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What does “we have” mean?  You *know* that it is true,  you *assume* that it is true, or you *guess* that it is true?

Comment: @MartinR I have tested this inequality numerically and I assume it's true

Comment: The LHS of the second inequality is not defined if any of $a, b, c$ is $\pi/2$.

Comment: @MartinR thanks I have corrected .

Comment: Note that your first inequality is *stronger* than https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2197138/42969, which has no (accepted) proof so far. I (personally) doubt that it will be easier to prove your version.