# Inequality $\frac{\ln(7a+b)}{7a+b}+\frac{\ln(7b+c)}{7b+c}+\frac{\ln(7c+a)}{7c+a}\leq \frac{3\ln(8\sqrt{3})}{8\sqrt{3}}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math, jensen-inequality, karamata-inequality

I'm interested by the following problem :

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $abc=a+b+c$ then we have :
>   $$\frac{\ln(7a+b)}{7a+b}+\frac{\ln(7b+c)}{7b+c}+\frac{\ln(7c+a)}{7c+a}\leq \frac{3\ln(8\sqrt{3})}{8\sqrt{3}}$$

I have tried to use convexity and Jensen but the result is weaker  . I try also Karamata's inequality but it fails totaly so I'm a bit lost .

If you have a hint it would be great .

Thank you .

Comment: Such symmetric inequalities always can be solved by taking $a=b=c$. in this case we can derive $a=\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: source of problem please?

Comment: @C.F.G: A symmetric expression does not necessarily attains  its maximum (or minimum) at a point where all variables are equal.

Comment: @MartinR, if maximum (or minimum) exist then the symmetric expression attains its maximum (or minimum) at a point where all variables are equal. isn't?  please give a counterexample? what happens for the answer of this question? has been deleted?

Comment: @C.F.G: $f(x,  y) = \exp((x+y)^2-(x+y)^4)$ is symmetric in $x, y$. The maximum is *not* attained on the line $x=y$. – The answer was deleted by its  owner (after someone pointed out that it was wrong).

Comment: About the deleted answer. The proof was based in the asumption that $\frac{\log(x)}{x}$ is concave in $(0,+\infty)$. I pointed out as a remark that this was not true. After that the owner of the answer delete it.

Comment: About the exteme points and where there apear, I have tested these inequalities in Mathematica numericaly and indeed we have maximum at $a=b=c=\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: About the owner of the deleted answer, I'm asking sorry. I didn't want to offend him. I just pointed out my comment as I write to you now. In never case I ask from him to delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that $\ln x \le \ln (8\sqrt{3}) + \frac{1}{8\sqrt{3}}(x-8\sqrt{3})$ for $x > 0$
(the proof is simple and thus omitted),
it suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{\ln (8\sqrt{3}) + \frac{1}{8\sqrt{3}}(7a+b-8\sqrt{3})}{7a+b}
\le \frac{3\ln (8\sqrt{3})}{8\sqrt{3}}$$
or
$$\frac{1}{7a+b} + \frac{1}{7b+c} + \frac{1}{7c+a} \le \frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}.$$
This has been solved in the link below:
[If $a+b+c=abc$ then $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{7a+b}\leq\frac{\sqrt3}{8}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197138/if-abc-abc-then-sum-limits-cyc-frac17ab-leq-frac-sqrt38/3256918#3256918)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by River Li, first show that for every $x>0$ holds the inequality
$$
\log x\leq\frac{x}{8\sqrt{3}}+\log\left(\frac{8\sqrt{3}}{e}\right).\tag 1
$$
The equality in $(1)$ for holds only for $x=8\sqrt{3}$.
From $(1)$ we have
$$
\sum_{cyc}\frac{\log(7a+b)}{7a+b}\leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{7a+b}\log\left(\frac{8\sqrt{3}}{e}\right).
$$
Set 
$$
\Pi(x,y,z):=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{7x+y},
$$
Consider the inequality
$$
\frac{1}{kx+ly}\leq \frac{A}{kx}+\frac{B}{ly},
$$
with $k,l,x,y>0$, $k=7$, $l=1$ and assume that
$$
\frac{A}{k}+\frac{B}{l}=\frac{1}{k+l}.
$$
Hence $B=\frac{1}{56}(7-8A)$. But for this value of $B$ it is
$$
\frac{1}{kx+ly}-\frac{A}{7x}-\frac{B}{y}=-\frac{(x-y)(49x-56Ax-8Ay)}{56xy(7x+y)}.
$$
Using $49-56A=8A\Leftrightarrow A=\frac{49}{24}$, we get
$$
\frac{1}{7x+y}-\frac{7}{64x}-\frac{1}{64y}=-\frac{7(x-y)^2}{64xy(7x+y)}\tag 2
$$
Summing all three equalities $(2)$ (for the pairs $(x,y),(y,z),(z,x)$) we get
$$
\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{7x+y}\leq\frac{7}{64}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{64}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x}
$$
and consequently
$$
\Pi(x,y,z)\leq\frac{1}{8}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x}.
$$
This is a ''bad'' estimate, since 
$$
\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x}\geq\sqrt{3}.
$$
However, I think, someone can work better with $(2)$ and obtain a ''good'' estimate.