# Hard refinement concerning the inequality $\frac{1}{7a+b}+\frac{1}{7b+c}+\frac{1}{7c+a}\leq\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, uvw

For me really it's a nightmarish refinement :

Claim :

Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $abc=a+b+c$ then we have :

$$\frac{1}{7a+b}+\frac{1}{7b+c}+\frac{1}{7c+a}\leq \left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)\frac{1}{1+7\left(\frac{1}{a\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{b\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{c\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{6}{5}}}$$

---

My attempt :

I have tried to make the problem more symmetric and I build the inequality :

$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{7a+b}+\frac{1}{7b+a}\right)\leq \left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1+7\left(\frac{1}{a\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{b\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{c\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{6}{5}}}+\frac{1}{1+7\left(\frac{1}{a\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{b\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{c\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{7}{4}}}\right)$$

Using uvw's method with $u=abc=a+b+c$ and $ab+bc+ca=v$ we get :

$$\frac{8(7u^2+43v)(7uv+65u)}{1764u^4+343u^2v^2+6622u^2v+79507u^2+1764v^3}\leq \left(\frac{v}{u}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1+7\left(\frac{v}{\sqrt{3}u}\right)^{\frac{6}{5}}}+\frac{1}{1+7\left(\frac{v}{\sqrt{3}u}\right)^{\frac{7}{4}}}\right)\quad (I)$$

But I'm stuck here because it's wrong...

---

Other attempt :

Let $a\geq b\geq c>0$ such that $abc=a+b+c$ then we have :

$$\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{7a+b}+\frac{1}{7b+a}-\frac{4}{13a+a+b+c}\right)\leq \left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1+7\left(\frac{1}{a\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{b\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{c\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{6}{5}}}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{7b+a}+\frac{1}{7a+c}+\frac{1}{7c+b}\right)$$

Where I use convexity .I cannot prove it and I think it's wrong too !

---

Last attempt :

$a,b,c>0$ such that $abc=a+b+c$ then we have :

$$\frac{1}{7a+b}+\frac{1}{7b+c}+\frac{1}{7c+a}\leq \left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)\frac{1}{1+7\left(\frac{\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+3}{9}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$

The problem is : it seems too good to be true even if I made some numerical check.The good news is : there is the homogeneity so maybe this inequality is true in some intervals !

How to show the claim ?

Thanks in advance !

Source : [If $a+b+c=abc$ then $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{7a+b}\leq\frac{\sqrt3}{8}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197138/if-abc-abc-then-sum-limits-cyc-frac17ab-leq-frac-sqrt38)

Comment: You should clarify the title is "Hard refinement of X", as opposed to the current format which suggestions "Hard refinement, which is X".

Comment: The only solution for equation $xyz=z+y+z$ is $x=y=z=\sqrt 3$, then we have:$LHS= \frac 3{8\sqrt 3}=\frac{\sqrt 3}{8}$. I dont think there can be an inequality.

Comment: @Sirous well what about $(1,2,3)$?

Comment: The conditions $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=abc$ imply that $a = \tan A$, $b = \tan B$, and $c = \tan C$, where  $A$, $B$, and $C$ are angles of an acute triangle.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Well the big problem here is the coefficient $7$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Can you confirm if my attempt is true ? If yes feel free to use it .

Comment: Sorry, I cannot confirm your attempt (and it looks more complicated than the initial inequality).