# How to show that the constraint $(C)$ exists?

Tags: derivatives, inequality, convex-analysis, constraints, buffalo-way

Let $\sqrt{3}<p\leq x\leq q\leq 8\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{3}< a\leq 8\sqrt{3}$  and the constraint $(C)$ then we have :

$$f(x)+h(x)+g(x)\leq \left(\frac{f(p)-f(q)}{p-q}+\frac{g(p)-g(q)}{p-q}\right)(x-p)+h(x)+f(p)+g(p)\leq h(x)+f(p)+g(p)\leq\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}$$

Where :

$f(x)=\frac{1}{7a+x}$$\quad$$g(x)=\frac{1}{7x+\frac{x+a}{xa-1}}$$\quad$$h(x)=\frac{1}{7\frac{x+a}{xa-1}+a}$ .

To prove the first inequality I use convexity remarking : the function $f(x)$ is obviously convex and using derivative it's also true for $g(x)$ on the interval $(\sqrt{3}, 8\sqrt{3}]$ . So it's a classical result using a chord of a convex function .

For the second we have :

$\left(\frac{f(p)-f(q)}{p-q}+\frac{g(p)-g(q)}{p-q}\right)(x-p)\leq 0$

And even :

$\frac{f(p)-f(q)}{p-q}\leq 0$$\quad$ and $\quad$$\frac{g(p)-g(q)}{p-q}\leq 0$

I don't prove it here because it's not hard .

The third can be seen as a linear function and solving the inequality in $x$ we got :

$$p\leq x\leq q=\frac{(2(-147\sqrt{3}a^3p^2+168a^3p-21\sqrt{3}a^3-21\sqrt{3}a^2p^3-4a^2p^2+123\sqrt{3}a^2p- 172a^2-28ap^3+18\sqrt{3}ap^2-4ap+24p^2))}{(49\sqrt{3}a^4p^2-56a^4p+7\sqrt{3}a^4+7\sqrt{3}a^3p^3-456a^3p^2 -41\sqrt{3}a^3p-8a^3-56a^2p^3+337\sqrt{3}a^2p^2-8a^2p+49\sqrt{3}a^2+49\sqrt{3}ap^3-400ap^2-287\sqrt{3}ap +336a-42\sqrt{3}p^2+392p)}\quad (C)$$

I give you the Wolfram alpha [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%287%28x%2Ba%29%2F%28x*a-1%29%2Ba%29%2B1%2F%287*a%2Bp%29%2B1%2F%287p%2B%28p%2Ba%29%2F%28p*a-1%29%29-sqrt%283%29%2F8%3D0) if there is mistakes .

To finish we need to show that the interval where there is $x$ is valid and I think we can use Buffalo's way . I'm stuck here...

How to show that the constraint $C$ is valid or exists ?

Thanks in advance .

Source :

[If $a+b+c=abc$ then $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{7a+b}\leq\frac{\sqrt3}{8}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197138/if-abc-abc-then-sum-limits-cyc-frac17ab-leq-frac-sqrt38)

Update 06/03/2021 :

Graphicaly speaking we have :

$$q=f(a)=\frac{(2(-147\sqrt{3}a^3p^2+168a^3p-21\sqrt{3}a^3-21\sqrt{3}a^2p^3-4a^2p^2+123\sqrt{3}a^2p- 172a^2-28ap^3+18\sqrt{3}ap^2-4ap+24p^2))}{(49\sqrt{3}a^4p^2-56a^4p+7\sqrt{3}a^4+7\sqrt{3}a^3p^3-456a^3p^2 -41\sqrt{3}a^3p-8a^3-56a^2p^3+337\sqrt{3}a^2p^2-8a^2p+49\sqrt{3}a^2+49\sqrt{3}ap^3-400ap^2-287\sqrt{3}ap +336a-42\sqrt{3}p^2+392p)}$$

Is increasing (I cannot prove it) for $a\geq\sqrt{3}$ so remains to show when :

$$f(\sqrt{3})> p$$

Comment: You really like to complicate existing inequalities (especially the tough ones) dont you?:)

Comment: @RiverLi any idea to kill it ?

Comment: @ErikSatie I do not receive your notification unless I commented here before you @ me. Your question looks complicated.

Comment: what does it mean for a constraint to exist?

Comment: @LinAlg Here the constraint is an interval so : Do you think that $I=[1,-1]$ exists ?Thanks.

Comment: It is still not entirely clear. Is your question 'is there an $x \in [p,q]$ for which (C) holds', or 'does (C) hold for all $x$ in $[p,q]$'?

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks! We need to show $p<q$ in fact so it's the second sentence you describe I think .

Comment: $p \leq q$ is part of your assumption: "Let $\sqrt{3}<p\leq x\leq q\leq 8\sqrt{3}$", so you cannot show that.

Comment: @Linalg Yes of course ,that's most clumsy of me.But it's not a big problem if we see the reverse problem , I mean if we start from the definition in $a,p$ of $q$.Thanks and feel free to comment.